# Gridview Paging disappears on adding pagesize

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have a GridView where I have to show top 200 records on page load and I have set the `pagesize="200"` in the design. But when I give this property Paging doesn't show in the GridView and when I remove the `pagesize="200"` property the paging shows up.

The actual case is when I remove the `pagesize="200"` I am only able to see only 10 records instead of 200 even though my DataTable returns 200 records.

I have also enabled `AllowPaging="true"`.

Can anyone please suggest an alternate or any inputs?  It is much appreciated.

**HTML Code:**

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"
                                    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="true" CellPadding="1" PageSize="200"
                                    CellSpacing="1" BackColor="#e7e7e8" BorderColor="#e7e7e8" GridLines="Both" CssClass="GridViewStyleB" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="10pt">

    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Position="Top" Visible="true" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#e7e7e8" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="left"  />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="RowStyle" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#a9a9a9" Font-Underline="false" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" HorizontalAlign="Left" BorderColor="#E7E7E8" ForeColor="Black" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" BorderColor="#E7E7E8" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#e7e7e8" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow pagerRow = (GridViewRow)gv.TopPagerRow;
        GridView1.VirtualItemCount = totalRecords;
        if (pagerRow != null && pagerRow.Visible == false)
            pagerRow.Visible = true;
    }
```

**Update1:**

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView1.TopPagerRow.Visible = true;
            int totalRecords = DAL.GetRecordCount();
            GridView1.VirtualItemCount = totalRecords;
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you please show your gridview html code?

Comment: @Asif.Ali - Updated html code.

Comment: try to add `AutoPostBack="true"` attribute to your gridview.

Comment: You said that your database returns 200 records. If you set pagesize=200 and you have only 200 records, you only have 1 page.

Comment: @Asif.Ali - I added `AutoPostBack="true"` and still paging isn't visible.

Comment: @BrunoQuintella - regardless of records I need to show the paging and that's what I'm trying to do. So each time paging is done next set of records alone is shown. The reason is I have a table with more than 500k records, so we are doing this as a part of performance tuning.

Comment: Are you able to post the code for the event OnPageIndexChanging ?

Comment: @IrishJoker - I handled them in prerender event and I'm able to see only 1 in the pager. For ex: If the table count is 1000 then 1000/200 = 5. So I need to have these 5 page numbers shown in the pager. I'm trying to achive this. So when anyone clicks on any particular page then I will handle them in pageindex event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have one page, you need to "force" it. 
Try it:

```
GridView1.BottomPagerRow.Visible=true

GridView1.VirtualItemCount = totalRecords;
```

And also change the property **AllowCustomPaging**: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-paging-with-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net-4-5/

Comment: This works! But I'm able to see only 1 in the pager. For ex: If the table count is 1000 then 1000/200 = 5. So I need to have these 5 page numbers  shown in the pager. I'm trying to achive this. So when anyone clicks on any particular page then I will handle them in pageindex event.

Comment: I have updated my code in the post and is this correct way and I handle them in prerender event?

Comment: You should set this property before you bind the data to your grid, not in the prerender. I just remember you also need to set the property AllowCustomPaging. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have updated my post with the changes and pager didn't yet show up.

Comment: It looks wrong, you should set these properties just before setting the DataBinding, not inside prerender. Take a look at the url I posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162525/discussion-between-learner-and-bruno-quintella).

Comment: I'm not using prerender event. I am handling everything in rowdatabound event only.